# What is the best way to allow someone to export a webpage to PDF for readability?

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have an online document which shows a report built dynamically from database values and application values. What type of report it shows to the user is based on various security permissions that a user has. So generally a Manager can see a full report, but a Customer Service adviser will only see part of that same report. It does this just fine.

But now the same report that is seen 'online' also needs a PDF version. I have started to build a new .CFM template which should handle rendering a PDF version of the same document. Its essentially a duplicate of the online version but with basic CSS formatting and change to way the document is structured (e.g. no jquery tabs). It still has the conditional logic in it.

But I have now come to a stage where I think it may be difficult to handle two files for the same document. What I mean is that if something changes in the 'online' version, then code in the PDF version also has to change.

Is this the only way to go about this or is there any better method of tackling exporting to PDF from a webpage? I just feel I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Check out http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ . You can use the same HTML for both the 'online' version and the PDF version and get close to 'pixel perfect' PDF. I have used this and simply write the output to disk (a web accessible directory), call `wkhtml2pdf` via `cfexecute` to generate the PDF and then delete the HTML file that was written to disk.

Comment: Heh... beat me to it mate... (@ScottStroz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cfdocument tag allows you to dynamically create PDF files.  You can allow users to choose their output formats in a variety of ways.

The one I use most often is to include a select control on the form where the user enters their search parameters.  My choices are generally HTML or Excel, but it's the same general idea.  When processing the form submission, I do the display stuff last.  It will resemble this:

```
<cfif form.showas is 'html'>
code for web page
<cfelse>
code for something else
<cfif>
```

Since your choices are HTML or PDF, the cfsavecontent tag might come in handy.

If your page is not accessed from a form, you could use cfsavecontent to generate a session variable with all the output.  Then, on your web page, offer a link or button or something that allows the user to render as PDF.  All you do is combine the session variable with the cfdocument tag and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: `cfdocument` is the 'easy' way to go to create unstyled PDFs, but formatting PDFs using `cfdocument` is a royal pain in the ass. I have recently started using http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ and it works great and is easy to use and format.

Comment: thanks Dan! I was also wondering about the logic and this has helped me out immensely. I was just using a simple hyperlink to request a PDF version but using a form has worked out better for me!

Comment: @ScottStroz You can use CSS inside of a `<cfdocument>`. On a good day it picks up some of the styling

Comment: And once in a blue moon it picks up the styling _and_ applies it correctly. ;) I've not used wkhtmltopdf, but I have used a similar pdf-converting wrapper for [qtwebkit](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/QtWebKit) and it was _way_ ahead of what cfdocument could manage. A colleague has used [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) (another qtwebkit-based pdf tool), but I got the impression that was a bit awkward to work with.

Comment: @JamesAMohler You can, but it is tedious to work with and, typically, nothing short of black magic will get the formatting to work as expected. Give me `wkthml2pdf` any day and I will be done in at least half the time over using `cfdocument`

Comment: @PeterBoughton I'm having consistent results with using CSS to format the PDF. The link to the CSS file must come after the <cfdocument> opening tag for it to work.  But... the styling in the PDF will almost always have to be different to the screen version so this leads to a challenge of providing a different stylesheet to style PDFs

Comment: And when you get to doing any non-trivial CSS you will be getting consistently wrong results, and you'll start jumping through hoops trying to get the damned thing to render how the various stakeholders have decided it must look. Avoid the hassle and use something decent from the outset.

Answer (score 4):

[wkHTMLToPDF](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/index.html) is a pretty good option for doing this.

I'm afraid your question - whilst a good one - will get closed due to it being too subjective to answer definitively.

As for the logic, possibly something like this

```
if (requestIsForPdfVersion){
    call wkHTMLToPDF passing the *html* version of the URL to it
    use cfcontent to set the mimetype and return the file
}
business as usual for HTML
```