# Converting Word HTML document to PDF

Tags: coldfusion, openoffice.org, coldfusion-10

I have a document that is generated via HTML/CSS and made to be a Word document (e.g., It uses Word formatting so that Word recognizes it as a Word document). I need to then convert this Word document to PDF. However, using `<cfdocument>` (with Open Office) returns an error. I've tried renaming the document to an HTML file, but specific Word CSS for things like page breaks and page numbers are not translated. Is there a way to convert these Word HTML documents into proper PDFs?

Comment: Skip the open office part.  Generate the content and then generate either a Word document or pdf, but not both.

Comment: cfdocument [does not support MS Word's "special" brand of html](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c21.html). The only program that can *reliably* interpret it is MS Word itself.

Comment: Also, cfdocument is "quirky" once you get beyond basic html formatting. You might want to check out some of the tools mentioned in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23410447/what-is-the-best-way-to-allow-someone-to-export-a-webpage-to-pdf-for-readability) , ie wkhtmltopdf, qtwebkit, etcetera.